# DateTimePicker script and style missing?

Tags: block-editor

I have a DateTimePicker Component in my Gutenberg Block. 
It seems, he's not correctly integrated :

- some styles are missing
- the zero of "05" minutes in the TextControl doesn't appear.

Is there anything I forgot ?
How can I change this ?

Here is my index.js :

```
const {
  registerBlockType
} = wp.blocks;

import edit from './edit';
import './editor.scss';

registerBlockType('pcfestival/date', {
  title: 'Date',
  category: 'pcfestival',

  attributes: {
    date: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  },
  edit,
  save() {
    return null;
  }
});
```

my edit.js :

```
const {
  Component,
  Fragment
} = wp.element;
const { DateTimePicker, TextControl } = wp.components;
const { __experimentalGetSettings } = wp.date;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { withState } = wp.compose;

class EditDateBlock extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }

  render() {

    const {
      attributes : {
        date
      },
      setAttributes,
      className
    } = this.props;

    const settings = __experimentalGetSettings();

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className={className}>
          <DateTimePicker
            currentDate={ date }
            onChange={ ( date ) => setAttributes( { date } ) }
            locale={ settings.l10n.locale }
            is12Hour={ true }
          />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default EditDateBlock;
```

and finally my plugin who enqueue scripts :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: PCFestival
*/

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

if ( ! class_exists('PCFestival')) {

  class PCFestival {
    protected static $instance = null;
    public static $version = 1.0;

    public static function run() {
      if( is_null(self::$instance) ) {
        self::$instance = new self();
      }
    }

    protected function __construct() {
      add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', array($this, 'enqueue_block_editor_assets'));
    }

    public function enqueue_block_editor_assets() {
      wp_enqueue_script(
        'pcfestival-editor',
        plugins_url('assets/blocks.editor.js', __FILE__),
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-date', 'wp-data'),
        self::$version,
        true
      );

      wp_enqueue_style(
        'pcfestival-editor',
        plugins_url('assets/blocks.editor.css', __FILE__),
        array(), // is there anything missing ?
        self::$version
      );
    }
  }

}

PCFestival::run();
```

[a capture of the TimeDateControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqArY.gif)

Comment: Do you have an example of a properly working date time component for comparison? It's not clear based on your GIF what the problem is, or what is missing

Comment: For example I don't have access to the shortcuts if I want to navigate with the keyboard. however I should, as the button on the bottom right says. the input with the controls is not intuitive.

Comment: As I can see the TimeDateControl import "react-dates" [github link](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e0cdf6809fd99dab1de2ed11802c42bbf85d4961/packages/components/src/date-time/index.js#L6) which is more intuite. I miss something...

Comment: You might want to raise an issue on GitHub and file a bug report